# String match is not working in python

Tags: python, string

here is my Django code

```
print request.user.role
print request.user.role is "Super"
print request.user.role == "Super"
print "Super" is "Super"
```

and the output on console is

```
Super
False
False
False
True
```

I am wondering why it is not matching the exact string

Comment: Try `type(request.user.role)`

Comment: `<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Group'>`

Comment: `print` prints whatever `str` returns, so you might compare `str(request.user.role) == "Super"`, but there's probably a better way.

Comment: And, never, ever use `is` to compare two values.

Comment: @thefourtheye `is` is an important part of the python language. Saying not to use it because someone is comparing an arbitrary object to a string is silly. `is` checks identity and therefore fails comparisons of distinct objects where `__eq__` returns `True`. That's useful behavior, even if it's unintuitive for novice programmers.

Comment: It does not look like a good idea to check roles by converting `user.role` to string and comparing with role name - it's error prone, potentially uses more memory and has plenty other things bad with it. There should be an enum with all the values and comparison should look like `user.role == roles.super` or `user.role.is_super` etc.

Comment: @sirosen I am sorry, I suggested him to not use that to compare two values

Comment: @pss Agreed! Example: if `user.role` is an instance of a subclass of `auth.models.Group` which overrides `__str__` with anything but `return "Super"`, this will fail erroneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do not use string comparison to check for user roles. This approach is error prone, may use more memory for new created strings and is dangerous overall. For example if value that represents role is not it's name you will have to keep track of name-value mapping yourself. Or if library will change it's mind and swap names to integers etc.

All libraries that provide such functionality has `roles` enum lying somewhere with all the values for roles.  So, for example, in [django-user-roles](https://github.com/dabapps/django-user-roles) you can do

```
user.role.is_super # maybe role.is_Super
# or
from userroles import roles
user.role == roles.super # maybe roles.Super
```

This is much more readable and safer aproach.

Answer (score 4):

It is because `request.user.role` is not a string. As a result, comparing it with a string `"Super"` will return false, as there is no implicit type comparison. You must *convert* it to a string if you want to compare it to one. To convert to a string, you can try this:

```
str(request.user.role)
```

Your last `print` returns true because you are just comparing the string `"Super"` to itself, evidently. Also as a side note, you only  want to use `is` when comparing identities, not values.